# How to run multiple plugin executions as a single argument to Maven?

Tags: java, maven

Is it possible to run *all* `<execution>` definitions on one maven command?

Like:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>first-execution</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.FooServer</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>second-execution</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>com.mycompany.BarServer</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
     </plugins>
 </build>
```

I could run `mvn exec:java@first-execution exec:java@second-excution` to run both, but is there also a maven command to simple tell maven to run just *any* `<execution>` that is found in the definitions?

Or at least, all executions that matches a `<goal>`?

Comment: I mean without having to qualify the execution-ids. Like `mvn exec:java` and then just pick up any `<execution>`.

Comment: Would be cool if you describe an application for this kind of feature.

Comment: Can you describe why you need that?

Comment: @JFabianMeier yes I can give an example: https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/2873 - the checkstyle plugin does not allow inheritance of rules, thus the only workaround is to split checkstyle into 2 jobs: one with default rules excluding unwanted, and one with additional rules that "override" the unwanted rules.

Comment: @membersound Why do you want to run checkstyle separately (not just in the build itself)?

Comment: Yes finally I will run that separately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Not possible and not planned as a feature](https://github.com/apache/maven/pull/357). As per Robert Scholte, Maven project lead:

> Maven is lifecycle driven. Being able to execute a goal from
> commandline is a feature, but **I don't see the need to execute all
> available exeucutionIds.**

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to use maven as universal scripting tool - it is written with the motto "convention over configuration".

If your build requires execution of external executables or Java code, you can bind executions to a maven *phase* like this:

```xml
<execution>
  <id>first-execution</id>
  <goals>
    <goal>java</goal>
  </goals>
  <phase>compile</phase>
  <configuration>
    <mainClass>com.mycompany.FooServer</mainClass>
  </configuration>
</execution>
```

If you call it with `mvn compile` then all executions bound to this phase (and all other phases up to this) will be executed. Usually in the order of their IDs, so you might want to set the id to something like `01-first`, `02-second`, `03-aaaa-third`.

For further information about configuration maven plugins, see the [official documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_.3Cexecutions.3E_Tag)

For a reference which phases exist and in which order they are executed (and in which lifecycle), there is also a nice offical documentation: [Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference)

Please note that some plugins are configured by default and also have bound several executions to phases by default (this is why e.g. a `mvn compile` compiles Java code without any configuration of the compiler-plugin).

Another alternative would be to switch to another build tool with a different philosophy, like [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) - this doesn't have dependency management included so nicely, but could be even called from maven. Or the [Gradle Build Tool](https://gradle.org/) that uses a DSL built on Groovy or Kotlin as configuration, so you can have a very flexible configuration (but don't do that there or you will not understand your own build configuration a few months after you have written it ;)

Comment: Thx for pointing this out, @Michael - I updated the answer a bit. (Also the answer includes the link to the lifecycle reference so one can look up the order of the phases easily.)

Comment: Not the downvoter, but while it's now more accurate, it still doesn't answer the question. The problem is that running a whole lifecycle phase executes way more tasks than OP wants to invoke. The reason is that what OP wants is sort of "anti-Maven" in philosophy. What they're asking for doesn't fit within the lifecycle model that Maven uses.

Comment: With that last sentence of the OP "Or at least, all executions that matches a <goal>?" I think that matching a phase is a reasonably good alternative (it seems quite useless to execute all executions or commands of a plugin, which this question suggests) - but only OP can decide about this. And in some cases you need to do this if you want to combine builds that include non-Java stuff (e.g. Frontend) with plugins - and in that light, the exec-maven-plugin is "anti-Maven" on its own.

Comment: "*it seems quite useless to execute all executions or commands of a plugin, which this question suggests*" I tend or agree (or at least, am yet to be convinced there's a good reason to allow it), and that's what the Maven project lead thinks too (see my answer), but that's what they're asking for.